# Token replacement by its value before indexing in apachesolr

Tags: 7, search

I'm using solr 4-x (apachesolr) for search functionality in my Drupal 7 site. I'm using a token in some long text fields in some nodes of different content types across my site. Lets suppose the token is [token_name] and its value is "test". So, whenever I search "test", the nodes containing this token don't show in search results. But when I search [token_name], the concerned nodes show in the search results.

What is happening here is that instead of the original token value, the [token_name] is stored in database. So, for indexing, the [token_name] is getting indexed instead of its value. And hence, it is unable to show results related to "test" as search keyword. Is there anyway to do this? Please suggest as I need to fix this ASAP.

P.S. I can't replace [token_name] by its value while saving the node by hook_node_presave.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `hook_apachesolr_index_document_build()` function to override node data index in apache solr

Comment: But how will I be able to replace all the tokens by their values? Because they aren't in a particular field of a particular content type. They can be anywhere.

Comment: u can use str_replace() function for this